# Keyed state store behaviour within ProcessWindowFunction (Apache Flink Java)

Tags: java, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I have a `ProcessWindowFunction` for processing TumblingEventTimeWindows in which I use a state store to preserve some values *across multiple tumbling windows*.
My problem is that this state store is not being preserved across tumbling windows i.e. if I first store something in window [0,999] and then access this store from window [1000,1999], the store is empty.
I am aware of the *global state* and *per window state* stated [here](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/stream/operators/windows.html#using-per-window-state-in-processwindowfunction). I want to use global state. I also tried creating a minimum working example to investigate this:

```
import org.apache.flink.api.common.state.MapState;
import org.apache.flink.api.common.state.MapStateDescriptor;
import org.apache.flink.api.java.functions.KeySelector;
import org.apache.flink.configuration.Configuration;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.TimeCharacteristic;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.datastream.DataStream;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.environment.StreamExecutionEnvironment;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.functions.AssignerWithPeriodicWatermarks;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.functions.windowing.ProcessWindowFunction;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.watermark.Watermark;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.windowing.assigners.TumblingEventTimeWindows;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.windowing.time.Time;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.windowing.windows.TimeWindow;
import org.apache.flink.util.Collector;

import javax.annotation.Nullable;


public class twStateStoreTest {


    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // set up the streaming execution environment
        final StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
        env.setStreamTimeCharacteristic(TimeCharacteristic.EventTime);
        env.getConfig().setAutoWatermarkInterval(1000L);

        final DataStream<Element> elements = env.fromElements(
                Element.from(1, 500),
                Element.from(1, 1000),
                Element.from(1, 1500),
                Element.from(1, 2000),

                Element.from(99, 9999)
                ).
                assignTimestampsAndWatermarks(new AssignerWithPeriodicWatermarks<Element>() {
                    long w;
                    @Nullable
                    @Override
                    public Watermark getCurrentWatermark() {
                        return new Watermark(w);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public long extractTimestamp(Element element, long previousElementTimestamp) {
                        w = element.getTimestamp();
                        return w;
                    }
                });

        elements
                .keyBy(new KeySelector<Element, Integer>() {
                    @Override
                    public Integer getKey(Element element) throws Exception {
                        return element.value;
                    }
                })
                .window(TumblingEventTimeWindows.of(Time.milliseconds(1000L)))
                .process(new MyProcessWindowFn()).
                print();

        // execute program
        env.execute("Flink Streaming Java API Skeleton");
    }

    static class MyProcessWindowFn extends ProcessWindowFunction<Element, String, Integer, TimeWindow> {
        MapState<Integer, Integer> stateStore;

        @Override
        public void open(Configuration parameters) throws Exception {
            stateStore = getRuntimeContext().getMapState(new MapStateDescriptor<Integer, Integer>("stateStore", Integer.class, Integer.class));
        }

        @Override
        public void process(Integer key, Context context, Iterable<Element> elements, Collector<String> out) throws Exception {

            if (stateStore.get(key) == null) {
                stateStore.put(key, 1);
            }else {
                int previous = stateStore.get(key);
                stateStore.put(key, previous+1);
            }
            out.collect("State store for " + elements.toString() + " is " + stateStore.entries().toString()
                    + " for window : " + context.window());
        }
    }




    static class Element {
        private final long timestamp;
        private final int value;

        public Element(long timestamp, int value) {
            this.timestamp = timestamp;
            this.value = value;
        }

        public long getTimestamp() {
            return timestamp;
        }

        public int getValue() {
            return value;
        }

        public static Element from(int value, long timestamp) {
            return new Element(timestamp, value);
        }
    }


}
```

Here I'm trying to count the number of times the `process()` function was called for a key. This example **works** and the state is indeed stored across tumbling windows. I've ensured that this example exactly mirrors the actual processWindow function, with other unnecessary code stripped off.

But state is **not** preserved across windows in the actual processWindowFunction!

Is there any gotcha that I am clearly missing to account for? 
Is there any other reason why state is not preserved across EventTimeTumblingWindows for a processWindowFunction that uses a MapState defined as follows:

```
private MapState<UserDefinedEnum, Boolean> activeSessionStore;

@Override
    public void open(Configuration parameters) throws Exception {
        activeSessionStore = getRuntimeContext().getMapState(new MapStateDescriptor<IUEventType, Boolean>(
                                                "name", UserDefinedEnum.class, Boolean.class));
    }
```

Here's the actual class with bloat removed and as per @David's and @ShemTov's suggestions:

```
public class IUFeatureStateCombiner extends ProcessWindowFunction<IUSessionMessage, IUSessionMessage, IUMonitorFeatureKey, TimeWindow> {

    private final static MapStateDescriptor<IUEventType, Boolean> desc =  new MapStateDescriptor<IUEventType, Boolean>(
            "store", IUEventType.class, Boolean.class);
    private final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(IUFeatureStateCombiner.class);

    @Override
    public void process(IUMonitorFeatureKey iuMonitorFeatureKey, Context context, Iterable<IUSessionMessage> elements, Collector<IUSessionMessage> out) throws Exception {
        ...

        MapState<IUEventType, Boolean> activeSessionStore = context.globalState().getMapState(desc);

        Iterable<Entry<IUEventType, Boolean>> lastFeatureStates = activeSessionStore.entries(); // <-------- This returns an empty iterable
        // even though I populated activeSessionStore with some values in the previous invocation of process()

        ... do something based on lastFeatureStates....

        activeSessionStore.put(...);
    }

    @Override
    public void clear(Context context) throws Exception {
        context.globalState().getMapState(desc).clear();
    }
}
```

And I invoke it using :

```
inputStream.keyBy(IUSessionMessage::getMonitorFeatureKey).
window(TumblingEventTimeWindows.of(Time.milliseconds(1000L))).
            process(new IUFeatureStateCombiner())
```

This still has the problem, I get an empty iterable in the second invocation of `process()` even though I populated the state in the previous invocation.

**Edit: Problem solved, the clear() method should not be invoked since this is a global state.**

Comment: I'm using Flink 1.10.1 FWIW.

Answer (score 2):

You want to do something more like this. And keep in mind that these are per-key state stores -- there's a separate map for every key -- so where do you are doing `stateStore.get(key)`, that doesn't really make sense. Perhaps all you need is `ValueState`, if you only need to store an Integer for each key.

```
static class MyProcessWindowFn extends ProcessWindowFunction<Element, String, Integer, TimeWindow> {
    private final static MapStateDescriptor mapDesc = new MapStateDescriptor<Integer, Integer>("stateStore", Integer.class, Integer.class);

    @Override
    public void process(Integer key, Context context, Iterable<Element> elements, Collector<String> out) throws Exception {

        MapState<Integer, Integer> stateStore = context.globalState.getMapState(mapDesc);

        ...
    }
}
```

Note that the global state store is never cleared. So if you have an unbounded key space, you'll eventually run into problems. You can configure [state TTL](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/stream/state/state.html#state-time-to-live-ttl) on the state descriptor(s) to deal with this.

Comment: The example was contrived to match the actual class. I tried this suggestion, but I still get an empty state. Please see the question, I added more info and what I tried. Thanks for the note, will keep that in mind. Edit:OHHH I got it, I was using clear() incorrectly!

Answer (score 2):

My mistake was that I was using the `clear()` method incorrectly. Since this is a global state, using the `clear()` method will clear the state as soon as the TumblingWindow expires. As David pointed out, global state is never cleared, and we have to define a TTL for unbounded key streams.

Answer (score 1):

As far as i know, you can't get the global state from the @override open method.

You need to get it from the process function on the ProcessWindowFunction:

```
context.globalState().getMapState(<your_Map_State_Descriptor>)
```

Comment: I tried doing it that way but still get the same problem. Also, if what you say is true how does the example I provided work (I'm getting the state in the `open()` method)?

Comment: when you get state in open() method it's windowed state by default if im not wrong (thats what i meant), Can you provide code when using context.globalState(), because it's should work.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that in your `minimum working example`, you just created `stateStore` in `open` function, and used `stateStore` directly in `process` function. While in the so-called `actual class`, you created `activeSessionStore` in `open` function but used `context.globalState().getMapState(desc)` to get the state. In my understanding, you never used the state you created in your `open` function, and always used global state. That's why when you added the `clear` function, it would become empty, and after you removed `clear` function it would work as you had expected. But actually you have verified in your example, you can achieve what you want without the global state like this:

```java
    ...
    @Override
    public void open(Configuration parameters) throws Exception {
        activeSessionStore = getRuntimeContext().getMapState(new MapStateDescriptor<IUEventType, Boolean>(
                                                "name", UserDefinedEnum.class, Boolean.class));
    }
    ...
    @Override
    public void process(IUMonitorFeatureKey iuMonitorFeatureKey, Context context, Iterable<IUSessionMessage> elements, Collector<IUSessionMessage> out) throws Exception {
        ...

        Iterable<Entry<IUEventType, Boolean>> lastFeatureStates = activeSessionStore.entries(); // <-------- Finally used the one you created in open function
        ... do something based on lastFeatureStates....

        activeSessionStore.put(...);
    }
```